# Colored dots on iCloud calendar are too dim, any setting i need to change?

Tags: icloud, calendar, color

When I add an event to my iCloud calendar, all the colors but purple have been dimmed for some reason, is there a setting I need to change to get the colors to stand out like they used to?

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the 'Edit' button in the top right portion of your calendar list
2. Click the color blob next to the calendar you want to change
3. Click custom color
4. Adjust the color value
5. Repeat
6. Click "Done"

[image]